# Monitor glowing greenish light after connected the 3rd monitor to the same graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

My graphics card is [Nvidia GeForce GTX 650](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650) which has 3 ports VGA, DVI and HDMI. It is also announced to support 3 monitors.

I connected 3 monitors to is and after 2 weeks, my oldest monitor connected to the VGA port, starts glowing a strange greenish or bluish light. I cannot change it in the monitor settings like changing light or color. And then it stops behaving like this.

Is this a signal that monitor is close to end?

Does this maybe mean that my graphics card is overburdened and that it may die soon?

I previously had 2 monitors attached to this graphics card for 1 year and I never had similar issues. They started after I bought the third monitor and connected it to HDMI port.

Answer (score 2):

Perform the following actions to diagnose the issue:

1. Unplug the signal cable for the monitor that's having issues. With it powered on the default image should appear. Usually the manufacturer logo.
2. Use the menu buttons and navigate the on screen display (OSD).

Does the monitor continue to exhibit the same blue/green odd light issue? If the issue persists while disconnected from the computer, it's the monitor. If not, it's something to do with the computer.

If the issue is with the computer:

1. Plug one of the other monitors into the same output the first one was plugged into using the same cable. Does it exhibit the same issue?
2. Try a different cable. Does the issue go away?

These tests will narrow down the source of the issue. If none of the above has any effect on the presentation of the green/blue image on the screen, then:

1. Reinstall the drivers. Fixed?
2. Boot to a live OS of some kind. Does the issue persist? If no, then OS related. Drives maybe? Some terrible Windows mystery you'll never solve?
3. If yes to #2: Shutdown the PC. Unplug all cables. Reseat the GPU. Fixed?

These are the basic steps in troubleshooting display issues. Hopefully you find the cause. If not, it may be worth finding another system and testing the GPU in it. If the issue follows the card, it's the card. If not, it's either the OS, or the mainboard of your system. This is similar to Step 2 in the last phase of testing above.

Good luck.